# Accessing named element inside of window resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

**Problem:**

I'm trying to access a named `Run` element within a `FlowDocument` which is defined in the Window Resources. To clarify what I mean, consider the follow code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <FlowDocument x:Key="doc">
        <Paragraph>
            <Run x:Name="run" />
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here, I'd be trying to access the `Run` element named "run."

**What I've Tried So Far:**

- Simply using the element's name to access it. However, named elements in the window's resources apparently don't have the same default accessibility as elements defined in the window's content, because this method did not work.
- Attempting to add a key to the `Run` element and then accessing the element through the `FindResource()` method. Unfortunately, it seems that keys cannot be added to nested elements.
- The following code, which throws a `NullReferenceException`:

  ```
  FlowDocument doc = (FlowDocument)FindResource("doc");
  ((Run)doc.FindName("run")).Text = "example text";
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.findlogicalnode.aspx) as

```
 var doc = this.Resources["doc"] as FlowDocument;
 ((Run)LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(doc, "run")).Text = "example text";
```

Remarks from above link:

> - The search direction for **FindLogicalNode** is toward child objects (**down the tree**); the search direction for the **FindName** methods is
>     towards parent objects (**up the tree**).
> - The FindName methods are governed by the concept of a XAML namescope. Using FindName you are guaranteed that only one object of
>     that name exists, because XAML namescopes enforce uniqueness. In
>     contrast, **FindLogicalNode ignores XAML namescope** and might cross XAML
>     namescope boundaries during the search.